# Most performant way to query products from multiple tables and combine results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I essentially have two core categories of products in a system with multiple manufacturers.  The current query in the system was written to handle only one product.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM "Config" c
JOIN "FirstProduct" fp ON c.id = fp.widget
JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
WHERE ts.app = ?appId
AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
```

What I want to get to: adding a query for another table, which I think can be done in two ways:

1. Effectively do both queries in one query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM "Config" c
JOIN "FirstProduct" fp ON c.id = fp.widget fpw
JOIN "SecondProduct" sp ON c.id = sp.widget spw
JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
WHERE ts.app = ?appId
AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
```

2. Do two separate queries, and UNION them.

```
with first_product_table as (
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM "Config" c
JOIN "FirstProduct" fp ON c.id = fp.widget
JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
WHERE ts.app = ?appId
AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
) ,
second_product_table as (
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM "Config" c
JOIN "SecondProduct" sp ON c.id = sp.widget spw
JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
WHERE ts.app = ?appId
AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
)
select * from first_product_table
UNION
second_product_table
```

This will be in a production system, so performance concerns are non-trivial.

Comment: On the query #1 and query #2 shouldn't the predicate `o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer` be inside the `ON` clause rather than in the `WHERE` clause? As it is now, this can convert your left join into an inner join unintentionally.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Do you mean the predicates in `first_product_table` and `second_product_table` should be in the `ON` statement three lines above them?  Why would it be different when combining the queries than when the query was originally written for one product?

Comment: No. Why do you use an outer join in the first place? As your queries are, the condition `o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer` will be always false when there are no matching rows on `ProductOffer` since comparing a `null` to anything is always false. If you want to include those rows, then place that filtering condition in the `ON` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Those two queries are not equivalent. According to your description the second one is the one that will produce the results you want. I made a small fix at the end:

```
with
first_product_table as (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.id
  FROM "Config" c
  JOIN "FirstProduct" fp ON c.id = fp.widget
  JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
  LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON o.app = ts.app
  WHERE ts.app = ?appId
  AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
  AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
),
second_product_table as (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.id
  FROM "Config" c
  JOIN "SecondProduct" sp ON c.id = sp.widget spw
  JOIN "TheSupplier" ts ON ts.name = fp.manufacturer
  LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
  WHERE ts.app = ?appId
  AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
  AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
)
select * from first_product_table
UNION
select * from second_product_table
```

If you are concerned about performance you'll need to make sure you have the right indexes. The follwing two indexes are the most important ones when the parameter `mlid` is specified:

```
create index ix1 on FirstProduct (manufacturer);
create index ix2 on SecondProduct (manufacturer);
```

Then, if the query is still slow, you can try:

```
create index ix3 on TheSupplier (name, app);
create index ix4 on ProductOffer (app, company, manufacturer);
```

**Final Note**: Please consider the condition `o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer` may filter out rows you may want, since it efectively negates the outer join, converting it into an **inner join**. Maybe you want the last four lines of each section look like:

```
  LEFT JOIN "ProductOffer" o ON (o.app = ts.app)
    AND (o.company IS NULL OR o.manufacturer <> fp.manufacturer)
  WHERE ts.app = ?appId
  AND (?mlid IS NULL OR ?mlid = fp.manufacturer)
```

But this is just a guess since I don't fully understand your requirements.